# Graphviz layout left to right, then top to bottom

Tags: graphviz

```
digraph finite_state_machine {
    size="8,5"
    rankdir=LR;
      node [shape = doublecircle]; beg, end;
      node [shape = circle];

  subgraph clusterG1 {
    label="area code";
    beg -> ac1 [ label = "(" ];
    ac1 -> ac2 [ label = "0,1,2,3,4,\n5,6,7,8,9,0" ];
    ac2 -> ac3 [ label = "0,1,2,3,4,\n5,6,7,8,9,0" ];
    ac3 -> ac4 [ label = "0,1,2,3,4,\n5,6,7,8,9,0" ];
  }

    ac4 -> ex1 [ label = ")" ];

  subgraph clusterG2 {
    label="exchange"
    ex1 -> ex2 [ label = "0,1,2,3,4,\n5,6,7,8,9,0" ];
    ex2 -> ex3 [ label = "0,1,2,3,4,\n5,6,7,8,9,0" ];
    ex3 -> ex4 [ label = "0,1,2,3,4,\n5,6,7,8,9,0" ];
  }

  ex4 -> num1 [ label = "-" ];

  subgraph clusterG3 {
    label="number"
    num1 -> num2 [ label = "0,1,2,3,4,\n5,6,7,8,9,0" ];
    num2 -> num3 [ label = "0,1,2,3,4,\n5,6,7,8,9,0" ];
    num3 -> num4 [ label = "0,1,2,3,4,\n5,6,7,8,9,0" ];
    num4 -> end [ label = "0,1,2,3,4,\n5,6,7,8,9,0" ];
  }

}
```

Gives this:

[image]

(Sorry so small :)

This is a simple linear diagram. I would like to have three boxes left to right, each box internally organized top to bottom. After a lot of googling, I am still not sure how to do this!

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you could just add [constraint](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:constraint)=false attribute to the edges which connect nodes between clusters:

`ac4 -> ex1 [ label = ")", constraint=false ];`

`ex4 -> num1 [ label = "-", constraint=false ];`

This attribute forbids the edge to be affecting the rank position of connecting nodes. In other words, it adds the connection arrow, but the position of head and tail remain as if there was no connection at all.

You will face another problem though — if your clusters are side by side, you will be connecting the **bottom** of one cluster with the **top** of the other which will lead to ugly overlapping edges through the whole graph.

If you'll have troubles in solving that, tell me how you want that problem to be solved and we can thing on the solution together.

[image]